# Value error expected singleton in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have a module named `uniform request`, which contains a field named `select product`, which contains inherited data from another module named `product`. Product, when I select the `product` I want to purchase a button shows named `send request to purchase`, after selection a confirmation button shows and after confirming the request I have the option to make new quotation, but when I try to make the new quotation an error message shows:

```
ValueError: Expected singleton : product. Uom()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to assign `UoM` (Unit of Measure) to the selected product, make sure that you insert a valid value of this field `uom_id`.